# How do I write a nested CASE statement that would compare two other nested CASE statements

Tags: sql, case

**The Goal:** To compare my "Status_W1" column with my "Status_Now" column to see if there was a shift in pipeline to higher stages in the sales funnel. I want to document every case where in my "Status_W1" column it says "Not Trial+" and where my "Status_Now" column says "Trial+". The output for that column should be essentially, if W1 Status = Not Trial+ and Status Now = Trial+ THEN 'Increased Stage' ELSE 'No Change'.

Here is my code so far: (Only including my SELECT section)

```
SELECT O.Opportunity_ID, O.Opportunity_Name, O.Account_id,Account_Name 
ACV_Bookings_USD_Converted, O.Close_Quarter, O.Close_Year, Opportunity_Owner_ID, 
O.Owner_Name, M.Region, Area, O.Stage, 
(CASE WHEN S.Date_Pulled = '2023-02-03'
    THEN S.Stage
    ELSE " " 
    END) AS W1_Stage,
 (CASE WHEN 
      (CASE WHEN S.Date_Pulled = '2023-02-03'
        THEN S.Stage
        END) IN ('Closed Won','Closing','Decision', 'Orders Processing', 'Proposal', 
'Purchase','Ready to Ship', 'Trial')
      THEN 'Trial+'
      ELSE 'Not Trial+'
      END) AS Status_W1,

  (CASE WHEN O.Stage IN ('Qualified', 'Incubate','Closed Lost')
    THEN 'Not Trial+'
    ELSE 'Trial+'
    END) AS Status_Now,

 (CASE WHEN 
      (CASE WHEN S.Date_Pulled = '2023-02-03'
        THEN S.Stage
        END) IN ('Closed Won','Closing','Decision', 'Orders Processing', 'Proposal', 'Purchase','Ready to Ship', 'Trial')
      THEN 'Trial+'
      ELSE 'Not Trial+'
      END) AS Status_W1,
```

How do I compare my last two CASE statements to each other so that I can assign my 'Increased Stage'/'No Change' designations? Still new to SQL, so sorry if this is messy or hard to understand!

Comment: Note that those are case _expressions_. (Case _statements_ are used in stored procedures. for conditional execution of code.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use another `CASE` with both conditions which used in `Status_W1` and `Status_Now` like this

```
 (
    CASE
        WHEN (
            CASE
                WHEN S.Date_Pulled = '2023-02-03' THEN S.Stage ELSE " "
            END
        ) IN (
            'Closed Won',
            'Closing',
            'Decision',
            'Orders Processing',
            'Proposal',
            'Purchase',
            'Ready to Ship',
            'Trial'
        )
        AND O.Stage NOT IN ('Qualified', 'Incubate', 'Closed Lost') THEN 'Increased Stage'
        ELSE 'No Change'
    END
) AS Pipeline_Shift --column name you want
```